# Extract data from table as dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am writing a python script in which I have to execute different command and store its output in string format. From command list the output of one command is in tabular form as mentioned below. Need guidance to extract the same output in form of dictionary. Any leads would be appreciable.

Sample output should be like:

{Shelf id: 1, MEMBER Type: prime, TID: Sub_6500_3}

**Command output:**

```
~ tidci TID_table rtrv_shelf

-----+-----------------+---------+------+-------+--------+------+------+-------
Shelf|      IP         | MEMBER  |Prime |Members| Dup P  |Dup P | TIDc | TID
 Id  |   Address       |  Type   |ShId  | Added | found  |Count |      |
-----+-----------------+---------+------+-------+--------+------+------+-------
   1 |  d.d.d.d        |   Prime |   1  |    1  |  FALSE |   0  |   a | xxxxx
-----+-----------------+---------+------+-------+--------+------+------+-------
```

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve data like this.

```
for row in table_name:
    details= {"Shelf_id":row[0], "MEMBER_type":row[2], "TID":row[3]}
    return details
```

Comment: The sample output is in string format.